Power shell to let a command process finish and output results using code in script
I'm trying to process a command that takes a long time (12 sec) to complete.
I login in through power shell script using telnet protocol and then send the command, but no results come out.
Other commands that take couple of seconds to complete work well.
Here is the script to connect to cisco switch and use CLI commands:
param (
    [string] $remoteHost = "192.168.1.252", 
    [int] $port = 23 ,
    [string] $userName = "TES1",
    [string] $password = "ElbitElbit12!",
    #[string] $command ="show inventory", work well
    [string] $command = "test cable-diagnostics tdr interface GE1", # no output to 
    [int] $commandDelay = 1000
)

[string] $output = ""


## Read output from a remote host
function GetOutput {
    ## Create a buffer to receive the response
    $buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 128
    $encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding

    $outputBuffer = ""
    $foundMore = $false
     
    ## Read all the data available from the stream, writing it to the
    ## output buffer when done.
    do {
        ## Allow data to buffer for a bit
        start-sleep -m 1000
     
        ## Read what data is available
        $foundmore = $false
        $stream.ReadTimeout = 1000

        do {
            try {
                $read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 128)
     
                if ($read -gt 0) {
                    $foundmore = $true
                    $outputBuffer += ($encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $read))
                }
            }
            catch { $foundMore = $false; $read = 0 }
        } while ($read -gt 0)
    } while ($foundmore)
        
    $outputBuffer
}
     
function Main {
    ## Open the socket, and connect to the computer on the specified port
    $test = $PSScriptRoot + "\\teslog1.txt"
    write-host "Connecting to $remoteHost on port $port"
     
    trap { Write-Error "Could not connect to remote computer: $_"; exit }
    $socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($remoteHost, $port)

    write-host "Connected. Press ^D followed by [ENTER] to exit.`n"
     
    $stream = $socket.GetStream()

    $writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream

    ## Receive the output that has buffered so far
    $SCRIPT:output += GetOutput

    $writer.WriteLine($username)
    $writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $writer.WriteLine($password)
    $writer.Flush()  
        
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $writer.WriteLine($command) 
    write-host $command
    #Start-Sleep -m $commandDelaySec
                   
    $writer.Flush()
    $SCRIPT:output += GetOutput
          
    $writer.WriteLine("exit")

    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    if ($output.Length > 0) {
        $output = $output.Substring(110, 30)
        write-host $output
    }

    $writer.Flush()
    $writer.Close()
    $stream.Dispose()
    $stream.Close()

    $output | Out-File -encoding ascii ("teslog.txt")
}

Try to connect and login through Telnet protocol and run CLI commands that take long time to complete.

TCP you may not get the entire response in one message.  So you have to keep on looping until you get all the data.  The only way you can tell if you get all the data is with a terminating character.  What charact do you get at the end of the response?  I would manually run the command with a Telnet app like Putty.  Check the terminating character.  The loop you code and wait until terminating character is in the response.

Not the issue at hand, but you'll want to change if ($output.Length > 0) to if ($output.Length -gt 0)
